# Sam Guevenne's quest won't start!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I am trying to start the quest "A night to remember" but after sam tells me i don't look good, he just exits the conversation. I read where this is usally caused by Ysolda being killed, but while I did the contest she was walking around me, so I know it is not that. If it helps, I am on the unupdated Xbox 360 version and i have completed all of the questlines.

Comment: Maybe the "unupdated" note is important?

Comment: Possibly, but the elder scrolls didn't tell that simply having an unupdated game would effect this.

Comment: Do you mean "unupdated" as in there is an outstanding update to the latest patch of the game, or do you mean as in you are using the original version of the game instead of the Special Edition? If it is the former then check the version - if it's pre-1.5 that could well be the problem. Before that patch the characters Senna, Ennis, and Ysolda were not essential and could die. Patch the game to the latest version then try to reload a save where all three of these characters are still alive.

Comment: As in i am playing the basic skyrim and have never updated it. Also, i think all are alive (cannot find her at the moment, but she should be alive since I did the heart of dibella quest)

Comment: I meant i cannot find senna

Comment: The fact that you haven't updated it really don't help. Skyrim is a massively complex game with tens of thousands of different play-through combinations. Sometimes one quest does something that stops another quest working correctly - Bethesda fix most of these during development but they do come out of the woodwork after release and are fixed with updates. Try updating the game (might take a while if you've never done it) and attempt the quest again.